# Storing location of characters in string

Tags: python

I am writing a Hangman program during my free time at school, as an entry level project for Python, and I have finally run into an obstacle.

## What I want to do:

So far I have printed a board to the size of the word inputted, and I can decide if the guesses are correct or not, with a working score. Now I need to take a correct guess, and change the correct underscores in str(board) into their actual letter. To do this I wanted to grab the locations of the character guessed (if correct) in the FULL CORRECT WORD and then simply change that position in board into the correct letter. Sorry for the wordyness! Here is my code.

```
print("Welcome to Tyler's Hangman game!!!! Player one, input a word for player two to guess, lowercase!\n")

playAgain = True
guessing = True
#assure game starts in the True state

while playAgain == True:

    word = str(raw_input())
    wordLength = int(len(word))
    board = "_ " * wordLength
    lives = 9
    #initialize/reset variables on a new play
    
    while guessing == True:
    
        print("\n" * 15)
        print("Now its player two's turn to make a guess! You have 9 lives! Only one letter at a time, lowercase!\n")
        print(board + "Lives: " + str(lives) + "\n")
        #print board + lives
        
        guess = str(raw_input())
        
        if guess in word:
            print("Correct!")
            word.index(guess)
            
        else:
            print("Wrong.")
            score -= 1
            #check guess and change board
```

The statement starting with if guess in word: is where things start to get confusing for me. Thanks!!

Snippet I'm confused with

```
        if guess in word:
            print("Correct!")
            word.index(guess)
```

Comment: What is confusing you about it. Can you explain what is not behaving as you expect?

Comment: `if guess in word` checks for the substring `guess` in the string `word`. If true, it prints 'correct' and then prints out the index `guess` first appears at. It's much cleaner to do `print(word.index(guess))`, of course.

Comment: Ah I suppose I did not understand what index did. I would not like to print the index, I would simply like to check at which points the character appears, then I want to use those integers later in the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to propose an alternative solution to your real problem. Mutating strings is not very idiomatic in Python and is prone to errors. My approach instead will be to keep track of which letters have been guessed and then compute the board state from that and the actual answer.

```
answer = 'hello world'
guessed = ['a', 'e', 'm', 'r']
def compute_board(answer, guessed):
    return ''.join(c if c == ' ' or c in guessed else '_' for c in answer)
compute_board(answer, guessed) # gives _e___ __r__
```

Now you can easily get the number of guesses from the length of the `guessed` list, you can check for repeated guesses easily by checking if their guess is already in the list, and you can add guesses easily by just adding them to the end of the list.

Comment: This is a much more compact and useful way to do things, thanks for the response. As I said I am new to the language and quite honestly coding itself, so I am always looking for ways to compact my lengthy and unecessary code, thanks!!